# Error flash output TypeError 1009:Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Why I get output

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.
>
> `at Untitled_1_fla::MainTimeline/asd()`

this my code

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,asd)
function asd(e:Event){
    if(test.pemukul.hitTestObject(musuh)){
        musuh.visible=false
    }
}
```

Comment: And using trace on the variables wasn't able to tell you which variable was null? You could have also used the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some object you trying to access is null
so check this objects:

```
test
pemukul
musuh
```

Comment: pemukul is movie clip in test