# FLASH , TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at pedangan_fla::MainTimeline/asd()

Tags: flash, adobe

null object is pemukul

why I get this error ,

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at pedangan_fla::MainTimeline/asd()

this my code :

```
trace(pemukul)
var pemukul:MovieClip = test.getChildByName("pemukul") as MovieClip;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,asd)
function asd(e:Event){
    if(pemukul.hitTestObject(musuh)){
        musuh.visible=false
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error flash output TypeError 1009:Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530439/error-flash-output-typeerror-1009cannot-access-a-property-or-method-of-a-null-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after recreating a simple scene with your code, I didn't get your error.
When you initially trace pemukul, do you get [object MovieClip] or do you get null?

I can reproduce an error when the test clip didn't contain a child named pemukul - can you double check to make sure a child of that name exists?